# Appium support with Xcode 8

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I have been facing issues with launching instrumentation using Appium and Xcode 8. I recently got to know that apple has removed automation from instrumentations because of which Appium(1.5.3) is not able to not working correctly.
Does anyone have a solution to it? Is it going to be fixed in Appium v1.6.0-beta1 version?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Instruments/UI Automation aren't supported by Xcode 8 anymore, so the Appium won't work with it. Now it has to support XCUITest, which replaces UI Automation.

Appium community is working on the new iOS Driver - now it is **XCUITest Driver**.

> Advantages of the new XCUITest driver:
>
> - Runs on sims and real devices, including TvOS
> - Is able to run on multiple connected devices in parallel
> - Is much faster (way faster)
> - Less buggy!
> - Better control of simulators
> - Can dismiss system-level alerts!
>
> Disadvantages:
>
> - Only works on iOS 9.0 and up
> - Still no Notification testing

You can have unofficial version by cloning the repo:

- clone the appium from the git : git clone
  https://github.com/appium/appium.git2
- go to the cloned folder
- execute command: $ npm install

(if shrink-wrap error occurs => execute:  $ npm shrink-wrap)

More info here: https://discuss.appium.io/t/ios9-uiautomation-what-is-appium-approach-to-uiautomation-deprecation-by-apple/7319/103

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 7.3 will work with appium 1.5.3.

Xcode 7.2 will work with appium 1.5.2.

When I used other versions I was getting connection error.

Comment: Tried with Xcode 8 Beta version. Was getting error.